# How can I show image passed as this.state in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to show an image using data fetched from API. I pass data fetched by API as state. When I rendered state, it doesn't show image and it shows alt in the browser.

I couldn't find the relevant information in Stack Overflow, it would be great if I can get some insight from you.

A part of data is as below:

```
{
 "elapsedMilliseconds": 33,
 "count": 359,
 "artObjects": [
    {
      "links": {
      "self": "https://www.rijksmuseum.nl/api/nl/collection/SK-A-180",
      "web": "https://www.rijksmuseum.nl/nl/collectie/SK-A-180"
    },
    ......
```

and my code.

```
export default class Collection extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data : []
     }
}
componentDidMount(){
    fetch(url)
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(json => {
        this.setState({
            data: json.artObjects[0].links.web
        });
     });
}
render(){
    
    return(
        <div>
        <h2> Rijks Museum Collection </h2>
        <div><img src={this.state.data} alt="img" /></div>
        </div>
        );
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url at `links.web` refers to an html page rather than an image, so it won't show anything in an `<img/>` element. I'm not familiar with the Rijksmuseum api, but it looks like `webImage.url` is the image you're looking for, so maybe try this:

```
    ..
    this.setState({
        data: json.artObjects[0].webImage.url
    });
    ..
```

(And replace `[]` with `''` in the constructor.) You may need to incorporate `hasImage` as well, in case an object doesn't have an image. And it's probably a good idea to rename the state property `data` to `imageUrl` (or `imageUrls` once you start using arrays.)

Comment: Thank you for taking time to check the API info. It worked now.